# How to apply multiprocessing on OBSPY stream?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The file I import with OBSPY has 207 traces forming a stream, each trace has 30k samples. The data from each trace is accessed by seismic_data[trace_number].data and is a 1-d ndarray.

I am using a function that takes a trace and an int as parameters:
kurt_1d(signal_1d, samples). It returns a 1-d array of the same size.

Currently I am using a for loop over the 207 traces to run the function over each trace:

```
def kurt_nd(signal_nd, samples):

    kurt_array = signal_nd.copy()
    for index in range(207):
       kurt_array[index].data = kurt_1d(signal_1d=signal_nd[index].data,samples=samples)
    return(kurt_array)
```

How can I apply this function kurt_1d(signal_1d, samples) over the whole stream (207 traces) using multiprocessing to boost the speed? The goal is to store each resulting 1-D ndarray in its respective index at the original stream copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a pool of processes to run the function.
A sample code is as follows :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

num_proc = os.cpu_count() # to get the number of cores on your computer

pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_proc)
proc = [pool.appy_async(kurt_nd,args=[i,samples]) for i in traces] # map the function to the processes
results = [p.get() for p in proc] # retrieve the results from your processes
```